# Django-allauth - adding additional fields using AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am trying to add additional fields ('`test`') using `AbstractUser`. I created a simple user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Next I create form:

```
class SimpleSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    test = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='test')
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.test = self.cleaned_data['test']
        user.save()
        return user
```

Everything is saved outside of my `test` field.

How to save the easiest data from the `test` field from my forms in my model `CustomUser`. Why it does not work in my example.

Comment: Are you add `SimpleSignupForm` to `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in `settings.py`?

Comment: it works, but it does not allow to change the names of form fields. I am looking for a solution that will allow me to save my 'test' field when I have specified in the settings.py file `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'app.forms.SimpleSignupForm'}`

Answer (score 3):

```
class SimpleSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    test = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='test')

def save(self, request):
        user = super(SimpleSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.test = self.cleaned_data['test']
        user.save()
        return user

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```